WSO2 website access to front site denied and possibility wrong packages or versions
Im trying to folllow these steps to access the front code but that npm install doesn't install the lerna packages no matter what the node version is.
Does anyone knows the solution
how i tried to run the commands
i tried to change the node js version but still the same

Have you changed or updated the package.json by any chance before or after running the npm install command? The mentioned error can happen if you have already installed Lerna v7 (or above) in your environment. Please check whether you have installed Lerna v7 or above in your environment and try performing a npm ci command to do a clean install of the dependencies.

Try migrating to workspaces.
Lerna — Replacing the Bootstrap Command
